# How to change onboard settings in lightdm?

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, onboard

How do I change the onboard settings for lightdm? I have a tablet with ubuntu on it. It was pretty easy to set up the onboard keyboard to show up in lightdm.... except I really don't like the way it looks.

I'd really like to access the settings menu for the instance of onboard that runs when lightdm shows up. It's not using the same settings as my user account. I tried changing the settings for the root account. Does lightdm run under a different user?

Is it possible to change these settings? Also for some reason the settings button that normally shows up on the keyboard is removed in lightdm.

I'm running 14.04 by the way.